# HBase filter inheritance consultation

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I need a filter which is a bit like TimestampsFilter except that it takes a time frame and applies every row with timestamp within this frame.
This is my implementation:

```
public class TimeFilter extends TimestampsFilter {
private long from;
private long to;

public TimeFilter(long from, long to) {
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
}

@Override
public ReturnCode filterKeyValue(KeyValue v) {
    long timestamp = v.getTimestamp();
    if (from <= timestamp && to >= timestamp) {
        return ReturnCode.INCLUDE;
    }
    return ReturnCode.SKIP;
}
}
```

Is this implementation good enough?
I couldn't find an existing filter that suites my need.
Any input?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use a [setTimeRange](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html#setTimeRange%28long,%20long%29) on the Scan?